# Dropzone fails on iOS 11

Tags: ios, laravel, google-chrome, safari, dropzone.js

Dropzone is working fine for me on laptop and iPhone 5 iOS 10.3.3

Recently bought an iPhone 7 iOS 11.1.2 and dropzone fails on upload. During my upload process I am extracting information from the EXIF including GPS tags.

Only error I can debug on mobile is

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (HTTP/2.0 500)"

The same images upload fine on Laptop.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar issue once with the EXIF data (also in `laravel` and `dropzone.js`).
As I can remember, there were some special characters / signs in some photo EXIF data.
We "solved" it this way via adding `try / catch` block, when reading the exif data. When it an exception is thrown, set `$exif = null` and then save the data and uploaded file.

```
if(isset($ext) && (strtolower($ext) == 'jpg' || strtolower($ext) == 'jpeg')) {
    try {
        $exif = @exif_read_data ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'FILE');
    }
    catch (Exception $exp) {
        $exif = null;
    }
}
else {
    $exif = null;
}
```

Maybe that is not the solution, but guides you in the right direction.